# How to map month name to month number and vice versa?

Tags: python, datetime, calendar

I am trying to create a function that can convert a month number to an abbreviated month name or an abbreviated month name to a month number. I thought this might be a common question but I could not find it online.

I was thinking about the [calendar](http://docs.python.org/library/calendar.html) module. I see that to convert from month number to abbreviated month name you can just do `calendar.month_abbr[num]`. I do not see a way to go in the other direction though. Would creating a dictionary for converting the other direction be the best way to handle this? Or is there a better way to go from month name to month number and vice versa?

Answer (score 136, accepted):

Create a reverse dictionary using the `calendar` module (which, like any module, you will need to import):

```
{month: index for index, month in enumerate(calendar.month_abbr) if month}
```

In Python versions before 2.7, due to dict comprehension syntax not being supported in the language, you would have to do

```
dict((month, index) for index, month in enumerate(calendar.month_abbr) if month)
```

Comment: the right answer is by Sian: 
month = calendar.month_name[month_no]

Comment: @afshin No, it's not. That is answering a different question from the one that was asked.

Answer (score 95):

Just for fun:

```
from time import strptime

strptime('Feb','%b').tm_mon
```

Comment: does this depend on your locale?

Comment: Python 2.7 | ValueError: time data 'Fev' does not match format '%b'

Comment: @DiegoVinícius pretty sure 'Fev' is supposed to be 'Feb' there.

Comment: @FawwazYusran Diego tried the locale language, but the command is working for English language month names only

Comment: This is terribly inefficient if used in a loop.

Comment: Works very well.

Answer (score 82):

Using [calendar](https://docs.python.org/2/library/calendar.html) module:

Number-to-Abbr
`calendar.month_abbr[month_number]`

Abbr-to-Number
`list(calendar.month_abbr).index(month_abbr)`

Comment: example:  list(calendar.month_abbr).index('Feb')      result:  2

Comment: For full month name use: `list(calendar.month_name).index('January')`

Comment: Not bad, but not terribly efficient if used in a loop to look up many month names.

Comment: @Mr.LanceESloan did you benchmark/verify this?  Sure, reloading the list every time is wasteful, but could store it before the loop, which is then fairly equivalent to other answers.  I'd not sure the cost/gain on index versus using dictionaries?  And if you want to avoid the extra module overhead, could importing just this function?  Which answer do you support as efficient.  As is, your comment isn't very helpful to more novice users like me looking for something efficient (yet reasonably straightforward)... so maybe you can help point us somewhere?!!

Answer (score 29):

Here's yet another way to do it.

```
def monthToNum(shortMonth):
    return {
            'jan': 1,
            'feb': 2,
            'mar': 3,
            'apr': 4,
            'may': 5,
            'jun': 6,
            'jul': 7,
            'aug': 8,
            'sep': 9, 
            'oct': 10,
            'nov': 11,
            'dec': 12
    }[shortMonth]
```

Comment: you can do the same thing this way: `month_cal = dict((v,k) for v,k in zip(calendar.month_abbr[1:], range(1, 13)))`, and then `month_cal[shortMonth]`

Comment: That's a good way. The way I suggested doesn't need an import statement. It's a matter of preference.

Comment: calendar.month_name just yields a month names list.

Answer (score 26):

Information source: [Python Docs](https://docs.python.org/2/library/datetime.html#strftime-strptime-behavior)

To get month number from month name use datetime module

```
import datetime
month_number = datetime.datetime.strptime(month_name, '%b').month

# To  get month name
In [2]: datetime.datetime.strftime(datetime.datetime.now(), '%a %b %d, %Y')
Out [2]: 'Thu Aug 10, 2017'

# To get just the month name, %b gives abbrevated form, %B gives full month name
# %b => Jan
# %B => January
dateteime.datetime.strftime(datetime_object, '%b')
```

Answer (score 18):

Here is a more comprehensive method that can also accept full month names

```
def month_string_to_number(string):
    m = {
        'jan': 1,
        'feb': 2,
        'mar': 3,
        'apr':4,
         'may':5,
         'jun':6,
         'jul':7,
         'aug':8,
         'sep':9,
         'oct':10,
         'nov':11,
         'dec':12
        }
    s = string.strip()[:3].lower()

    try:
        out = m[s]
        return out
    except:
        raise ValueError('Not a month')
```

example:

```
>>> month_string_to_number("October")
10 
>>> month_string_to_number("oct")
10
```

Comment: This one is better than mine above

Answer (score 11):

**Full month name to month number (e.g. *January*, *February*, etc..):**

```
import datetime

month_name = 'January'
month_num = datetime.datetime.strptime(month_name, '%B').month

print(month_num, type(month_num))

>> 1 <class 'int'>
```

**Partial month name to month number (e.g. *Jan*, *Feb*, etc..):**

```
import datetime

month_name = 'Feb'
month_num = datetime.datetime.strptime(month_name, '%b').month

print(month_num, type(month_num))

>> 2 <class 'int'>
```

You can also format it to double-digits representation:

```
month_num = 3
formatted = f"{month_num:02}"

print(formatted, type(formatted))

>> 03 <class 'str'>
```

**Month number to full month name (either double-digits representation or not, either string or int) (e.g. *'01'*, *1*, etc..):**

```
import datetime

month_num = '04'  # month_num = 4 will work too
month_name = datetime.datetime(1, int(month_num), 1).strftime("%B")

print(month_name)

>> April
```

**Month number to partial month name (either double-digits representation or not, either string or int) (e.g. *'01'*, *1*, etc..):**

```
import datetime

month_num = 5  # month_num = '05' will work too
month_name = datetime.datetime(1, int(month_num), 1).strftime("%b")

print(month_name)

>> May
```

Comment: good answer, a catchall for month name to number (for full or partial names): `datetime.datetime.strptime(month_name[:3], '%b').month`

Answer (score 10):

One more:

```
def month_converter(month):
    months = ['Jan', 'Feb', 'Mar', 'Apr', 'May', 'Jun', 'Jul', 'Aug', 'Sep', 'Oct', 'Nov', 'Dec']
    return months.index(month) + 1
```

Answer (score 1):

To get the full calendar name from the month number, you can use calendar.month_name. Please see the documentation for more details: https://docs.python.org/2/library/calendar.html

```
month_no = 1
month = calendar.month_name[month_no]

# month provides "January":
print(month)
```

Answer (score 1):

When converting the month names to a list, you can use the `index` method. The index of the month name will correspond to the number of the month:

```py
list(calendar.month_abbr).index('Jan')  # returns 1
```

This is the reverse operation of `calendar.month_abbr[1]`.

Comment: Avoid code only answer and provide an explanation.

Answer (score 0):

```
form month name to number
d=['JAN','FEB','MAR','April','MAY','JUN','JUL','AUG','SEP','OCT','NOV','DEC']
N=input()
for i in range(len(d)):
    if d[i] == N:
        month=(i+1)
print(month)
```

Comment: Explaining your coding is always better

Answer (score 0):

You could try with:

```
pd.to_datetime(df['month'], format='%b').dt.month
```

Answer (score -1):

Building on ideas expressed above, This is effective for changing a month name to its appropriate month number:

```
from time import strptime
monthWord = 'september'

newWord = monthWord [0].upper() + monthWord [1:3].lower() 
# converted to "Sep"

print(strptime(newWord,'%b').tm_mon) 
# "Sep" converted to "9" by strptime
```

Comment: Maybe I'm misreading what you're going for, but are you sure it shouldn't be word[0:3]?

Comment: No, if you look again you'll see that the first letter word[0] is used in uppercase and concatenated to the next two letters, word[1:3].
The code I posted works really nicely in converting month words to their appropriate month number.

Answer (score -1):

You can use below as an alternative.

1. Month to month number:

`from time import strptime`

`strptime('Feb','%b').tm_mon`

2. Month number to month:

`import calendar`

`calendar.month_abbr[2]` or
`calendar.month[2]`

Comment: Thank you. This fixed a problem I have been struggling with for a very long time.

Answer (score -1):

```
def month_num2abbr(month):
    month = int(month)
    import calendar
    months_abbr = {month: index for index, month in enumerate(calendar.month_abbr) if month}
    for abbr, month_num in months_abbr.items():
        if month_num==month:
            return abbr
    return False

print(month_num2abbr(7))
```

Comment: Welcome.  Thanks for taking the time to provide an answer to the question. Since there is often more than one answer provided, it usually helps the question asker when you include a short description of what your solution does and why it's best.

Answer (score -1):

If you don't want to import the calendar library, and need something that is a bit more robust -- you can make your code a little bit **more dynamic to inconsistent text input** than some of the other solutions provided. You can:

1. Create a `month_to_number` dictionary
2. loop through the `.items()` of that dictionary and check if the lowercase of a string `s` is in a lowercase key `k`.

---

```
month_to_number = {
'January' : 1,         
'February' : 2,         
'March' : 3,           
'April' : 4,              
'May' : 5, 
'June' : 6,
'July' : 7, 
'August' : 8, 
'September' : 9, 
'October' : 10, 
'November' : 11, 
'December' : 12}

s = 'jun'
[v for k, v in month_to_number.items() if s.lower() in k.lower()][0]

Out[1]: 6
```

Likewise, if you have a list `l` instead of a string, you can add another `for` to loop through the list. The list I have created has inconsistent values, but the output is still what would be desired for the correct month number:

```
l = ['January', 'february', 'mar', 'Apr', 'MAY', 'JUne', 'july']
[v for k, v in month_to_number.items() for m in l if m.lower() in k.lower()]

Out[2]: [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7]
```

The use case for me here is that I am using `Selenium` to scrape data from a website by automatically selecting a dropdown value based off of some conditions. Anyway, this requires me relying on some data that I believe our vendor is manually entering to title each month, and I don't want to come back to my code if they format something slightly differently than they have done historically.