# convert a column in a python pandas from STRING MONTH into INT

Tags: python-2.7, pandas, monthcalendar

In Python 2.7.11 & Pandas 0.18.1:

If we have the following csv file:

```
YEAR,MONTH,ID
2011,JAN,1
2011,FEB,1
2011,MAR,1
```

Is there any way to read it as a Pandas data frame and convert the MONTH column into strings like this?

```
YEAR,MONTH,ID
2011,1,1
2011,2,1
2011,3,1
```

Some pandas functions such as "dt.strftime('%b')" doesn't seem to work.  Could someone enlighten?

Answer (score 28, accepted):

I guess the easiest and one of the fastest method would be to create a mapping dict and map like as follows:

```
In [2]: df
Out[2]:
   YEAR MONTH  ID
0  2011   JAN   1
1  2011   FEB   1
2  2011   MAR   1

In [3]: d = {'JAN':1, 'FEB':2, 'MAR':3, 'APR':4, }

In [4]: df.MONTH = df.MONTH.map(d)

In [5]: df
Out[5]:
   YEAR  MONTH  ID
0  2011      1   1
1  2011      2   1
2  2011      3   1
```

you may want to use `df.MONTH = df.MONTH.str.upper().map(d)` if not all `MONTH` values are in upper case

another more slower but more robust method:

```
In [11]: pd.to_datetime(df.MONTH, format='%b').dt.month
Out[11]:
0    1
1    2
2    3
Name: MONTH, dtype: int64
```

**UPDATE:** we can create a mapping automatically ([thanks to @Quetzalcoatl](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42684530/convert-a-column-in-a-python-pandas-from-string-month-into-int/42684545?noredirect=1#comment82085780_42684545))

```
import calendar

d = dict((v,k) for k,v in enumerate(calendar.month_abbr))
```

or alternatively (using only Pandas):

```
d = dict(zip(range(1,13), pd.date_range('2000-01-01', freq='M', periods=12).strftime('%b')))
```

Comment: to generate the dictionary:
import calendar
dict((v,k) for k,v in enumerate(calendar.month_abbr))

courtesy of:
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3418050/month-name-to-month-number-and-vice-versa-in-python

Answer (score 2):

Here's a one-liner using the `pandas` API and the `calendar.month_abbr` convenience:

```
from calendar import month_abbr

lower_ma = [m.lower() for m in month_abbr]

# one-liner with Pandas
df['MONTH'] = df['MONTH'].str.lower().map(lambda m: lower_ma.index(m)).astype('Int8')
```

1. Convert the `calendar.month_abbr` which are title-cased, into lower-cased
2. Feed the lowered-cased `MONTH` series to a `map` method >> `.str.lower()`
3. Use a `lambda` function within the `map` method and get the index of the corresponding month abbreviation  via the  `.index` python list method >> `.map(lambda m: lower_ma.index(m))`
4. Convert to integer >> `.astype('Int8')`

Answer (score -1):

Following Max's last point; create the same thing but rely on your local dataframe's way of encoding months:

```
# create mapping
d = dict((v,k) for k,v in zip(range(1, 13), df.Month.unique()))
# create column
df['month_index'] = df['Month'].map(d)
```