# How to change month name to a number?

Tags: python

I started learing python this month. I am a beginner so I am having problems with changing month name to numbers. I tried using `if` command but it does not work.

The code that I use is:

```
d = int(input())
m = input()
y = int(input())
a = y - 1900

if m == january:
    x = 1

print(f'It is {d} days, {x} months and {a} years at {d m y}.')
```

But it does not work and the program shows me that name `january` is not defined. How can I change name of months to numbers?

Comment: You have to do m == 'january', otherwise you are referring to the variable january

Comment: Kindly follow the link below for an answer to a similar question: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3418050/month-name-to-month-number-and-vice-versa-in-python

Comment: Kindly follow the link below to answer to a similar question: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3418050/month-name-to-month-number-and-vice-versa-in-python

Answer (score 1):

Your January isn’t in quotes so Python reads it as a variable. It should be `m == ‘January’` to  make it work.

Answer (score 1):

you should use strptime module.

For example:

```
from time import strptime
input_month = 'January'
input_month = input_month[:3]
strptime(input_month,'%b').tm_mon
```

Answer (score 0):

`if m.lower() == "january":`

- `january` is a variable, but you need a string: `"january"`
- To make user input case-insensitive, use `m.lower()`: converts all input characters to lowercase

To account for all months, and trigger user for a valid input (if invalid), you can do, compactly:

```
months_indices = {"january":1, "february":2, "march":3, "april":4, "may":5, "june":6,
       "july":7, "august":8, "september":9, "october":10, "november":11, "december":12}

while m.lower() not in months_indices:
    m = input("Please enter a valid month")
x = months_indices[m.lower()] # index into a dictionary to return one of 1,2,...,12
```

Answer (score 0):

> the program shows me that name january is not defined

To explain, Python looks at your program and needs to know which are `variables` and which are `strings`. When you use `january` without quotes ('), the Python interpreter thinks you want to use `january` as a variable. It looks for the `january` variable, but cannot find it, because it doesn't exist.

What you need is probably to compare if m.lower() to the string, january. To do this, all you need is to wrap january in either single quotes ('), or double quotes (") (Python accepts both).

The line will look like this:

`if m == 'january':`

Hope that helps!

Answer (score 0):

I also think dictionary would be a good idea:

```
d = int(input('Please enter an integer for days:\t'))
m = input('Please enter the lowercase name of the month:\t')
y = int(input('Please enter an integer for the year:\t'))
a = y - 1900

months = {'january': 1, 'february': 2}

for index, item in enumerate(months):
    if m == item.lower():
        print(f'It is {d} days, {months[item]} months and {a} years at {d} {m} {y} .')
    break
```

Answer (score -2):

The last paragraph remove the 'f' after the parenthesis

Comment: That is an f-string, please consult [here](https://cito.github.io/blog/f-strings/) for details.