# How to use datetime methods to parse a date with mixed structure?

Tags: python, datetime

How can I parse the string below into datetime using the strptime method?

```
s = ' 1:00 PM, May 20, 2020'
```

Comment: what do you mean by "*mixed structure*"?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How can I account for period (AM/PM) using strftime?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1759455/how-can-i-account-for-period-am-pm-using-strftime)

Comment: Does this answer your question? [month name to month number and vice versa in python](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3418050/month-name-to-month-number-and-vice-versa-in-python)

Answer (score 0):

```
import time    
time.strptime(' 1:00 PM, May 20, 2020', " %H:%M PM, %B %d, %Y")
```

Comment: no. please use `' %I:%M %p, %B %d, %Y'` as format. %I for 12h clock, %p to parse AM/PM.