# Converting a month name to the corresponding number. (Python)

Tags: python

I am extremely new to coding and I'm currently working with this.

```
print("What month were you born?")
m = input()

print("What day were you born?")
d = input()

print("What year were you born?")
y = input()

print("Your birthday is " + m + "/" + d + "/" + y)
```

If I input January 1 2000 for my birthday I get January/1/2000 but the output I want is 1/1/2000. Any advice?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [month name to month number and vice versa in python](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3418050/month-name-to-month-number-and-vice-versa-in-python)

Comment: checkout datetime module

Comment: Why ask the user to type in the month name and the date components separately? What if they mis-type it? Why not simply ask for birth date in a specific format e.g. YYYY-MM-DD?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need a way to map the month name to the number representing the month.  This can be done with a list or dictionary. Below we have a list of months.  The number representing that month is simply the index of the month in the list + 1:

```
print("What month were you born?")
m = input()

print("What day were you born?")
d = input()

print("What year were you born?")
y = input()

months = ["January", "February", "March", "April", "May", "June", "July", "August", "September", "October", "November", "December"]

print("Your birthday is " + str(months.index(m)+1) + "/" + d + "/" + y)
```

You can build upon this and add code to make the input case-insensitive and catch exceptions if the user enters the wrong value.

Comment: It works exactly how I wanted, Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

```
print("What month were you born?")
m = input()
newm = 'lol'
if m == "January" or "january":
    newm = '1'
if m == "February" or "february":
    newm = '2'
#KEEP GOING TILL DECEMBER

print("What day were you born?")
d = input()

print("What year were you born?")
y = input()

print("Your birthday is " + newm + "/" + d + "/" + y)
```

The other comments here are suggesting things that aren't on your level of skill. I think this answers your question in a way that you can understand what is happening.

When you get better, there are better ways to go about doing this, such what the other comments have suggested. There are even better ways of doing this code lol such as ignoring case on January/january.

Comment: I just got 2 as the month no matter what i put, thank you regardless, another user posted something that worked.