# Returning the month number instead of month name

Tags: python, return

I'm making an age calculator and when calculating the months, I need numbers, not strings such as "January" etc. how do I make it that when the user's selecting their birth month, they see month strings ("Jan", "Feb"), and backend I return the month's number?

thought this could be done with if statements, but it's simply too long and I wonder if there's a better way.

(I'm programming in python btw)

Comment: If you have a list of valid month names, like `["jan", "feb", ...]`, use `index` on that list, possibly offset by 1 and after some normalization (e.g. first 3 letters, lowercased).

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3418050/how-to-map-month-name-to-month-number-and-vice-versa should be helpful. btw please do it a read : https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Answer (score 0):

You can use dictionary.

Try the following:

```
selected_month = 'January'
months = {
    'January': 1,
    'February': 2,
    ...,
    ...
}
month_num = months[selected_month]
print(month_num)
```

Output:

```
1
```

Comment: This approach assumes the programmer knows about the ``months`` structure (how the months are typed? capitalized or not? what is the return type?). ``Enum``s supports type hinting in many IDES and you cannot mess up its usage in a programming environment

Answer (score 0):

How about using an `Enum`?

```py
from enum import Enum 

class Month(Enum):
    JANUARY = 1
    FEBRUARY = 2
    MARCH = 3 
    APRIL = 4
    ...
```

Then you can access the month index as

```py
m = Month.JANUARY.value
```

If typing `.value` bothers you, try to use a mixin with `int` such as

```py
class Month(int, Enum):
    ...
```

This way your month number will be accessible via the enumerable itself.

Answer (score 0):

You also have the option of using the built-in `datetime` module so you don't have to define the lookup dictionary yourself:

```
from datetime import datetime
month_name = 'march'
month_num = datetime.strptime(month_name, '%B').month
print(month_num)
```

prints: `3`

If the month names are short form ('mar'), change `%B` to `%b`. You could define a function to accept either using `try...except`.