# How to make it possible to input name of a month but then immediately convert it to the number of the month and use it as an integer in while loop?

Tags: python, python-3.x, dictionary, while-loop, valueerror

I made an age calculator in python which uses while loops to regulate the kind of answer the user can input.

```
while True:
    try:
        month = int(input("What is your birth month?\n"))
        if month < 13 and month > 0:
            break
        else:
            print("Error: You must enter a valid month.")
            continue
    except ValueError:
        print("Error: You must enter a whole number.")
        continue
```

However, I also want the user to be able to enter the name of the month but have it converted to its number value before the ValueError denies the response because it's not an int value. I'm pretty sure I need to keep the ValueError so that the user cannot enter random words and then have the program crash, but I also don't know how to bypass it to allow input of certain words because they will be converted to int value (the month names like january). I've tried using dictionaries and assigning each month their numerical value, but despite many attempts I don't know how to place it so it actually works.

I made a dictionary:

```
monthConversions = {
    "january": 1,
    "february": 2,
    "march": 3,
    "april": 4,
    "may": 5,
    "june": 6,
    "july": 7,
    "august": 8,
    "september": 9,
    "october": 10,
    "november": 11,
    "december": 12
}
```

and I figured I should probably do monthConversions.get(month) or monthConversions.get(int(month)) but no matter where I put it, the program either gets stuck because the ValueError keeps on denying the response or it gives me this error:

invalid literal for int() with base 10

I've also tried completely excluding the except ValueError: part of the code, but an except or finally block is required and at the end of the day I still want the user to get an error if they input a non-numerical value that is also not a dictionary key.

I also tried altering this: month = int(input("What is your birth month?\n")) to not only accept int values, but the program either gets stuck (doesn't accept any kind of response) or doesn't work at all.
I tried defining the month variable outside of the loop:

```
month = ""
```

but that pretty much broke the program.

I experimented with a lot of parts of the code but nothing came even close to working properly. I just can't figure out for the life of me how I'm supposed to make this work, despite the answer probably being simple lol. Any suggestions are welcome :D

Comment: can this help you? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3418050/how-to-map-month-name-to-month-number-and-vice-versa

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could do something like this:

```
monthConversions = { "january": 1, "february": 2, "march": 3, "april": 4, "may": 5, "june": 6, "july": 7, "august": 8, "september": 9, "october": 10, "november": 11, "december": 12 }

while True:
    in_str = input("What is your birth month?\n")
    in_str = monthConversions.get(in_str.lower(),in_str)
    try:
        month = int(in_str)
        if month > 12 or month < 1:
            raise ValueError
        break
    except ValueError:
        print("Error: You must enter a month name or whole number from 1 to 12")

print("\nmonth is", month)
```