# Python module defining constants for month numbers?

Tags: python, datetime, calendar

The `calendar` module defines constants e.g. `MONDAY` (0), `TUESDAY` (1), etc. for the [days of the week](https://docs.python.org/3/library/calendar.html#calendar.MONDAY).

And the source code even [defines](https://github.com/python/cpython/blob/main/Lib/calendar.py#L41) (but does not export) constants for `January` (1) and `February` (2), but not the rest of the months.

I can of course throw in a dozen of these definitions in a small module of my own. But given how common these must be, I'm left wondering:

**Is there a standard python module defining constants for all of the months?**

Comment: you mean like an enum? for a mapping, see [this q&a](https://stackoverflow.com/q/3418050/10197418).

Comment: Sure, could be. I basically want to be able to do `from some_module import APRIL`, and then use `APRIL` instead of 4 where needed e.g. to initialise a `datetime.date` object.

Comment: I'd probably just use an [IntEnum](https://docs.python.org/3/library/enum.html#enum.IntEnum). But I agree, it seems a bit inconsistent for the calendar module to define weekdays but not months. Maybe make a feature request?

Comment: Started: https://discuss.python.org/t/define-constants-for-month-numbers-in-calendar-module/25999?u=nokyotsu

Comment: There is also now an open issue: https://github.com/python/cpython/issues/103636